# Swapping Buttons in array

Tags: arrays, qt, swap

I have an array of my custom made buttons:

```
Button buttons[5]
```

Now I want to swap two elements of this array, for example buttons[1] and buttons[2]. How do I do this? Just stating the following, doesnt work:

```
Button help = buttons[1];
buttons[1] = buttons[2];
buttons[2] = help;
```

Can anybody help me with this?

I have solved using a pointer array:

```
Button *pntArray[5];
Button *help;
pntArray[0]=&buttons[0];
pntArray[1]=&buttons[1];

help=pntArray[0];
pntArray[0]=pntArray[1];
pntArray[1]=help;
```

Comment: This isn't what I meant, you are making things more complicated for yourself.  Instantiate your `Button` instances on the heap and store the resulting pointers in `buttons`, you can rearrange the order of your pointers to your heart's content without having two lists to maintain (it's also more of a `Qt` style).  I also recommend using a `QVector` (or any other STL-compatible random access container) to hold your pointers, then you can use `std::swap` to make your life easier.

Comment: Can you show me what this would look like in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QObject` base class does not allow the assignment operator or the copy constructor.  Unless you have manually created these (which is usually [unwise](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/object.html#identity-vs-value)), declare your instances on the heap and use pointers in the array instead.

```
//  Instantiate the buttons however you like, if you were just creating them
//  on the stack before, a default initialisation should suffice.  Though
//  normally in Qt you would at least pass the 'owning' widget as the parent
//  so you don't need to worry about deleting the buttons.
QVector<Button*> buttons(5);
for ( Button* button : buttons ) {  // C++11 only!
    button = new Button();
}

//  Then whenever you need to swap two entries:
std::swap( buttons[1], buttons[2] );
```

Comment: That's not quite true: it only applies to the base `QObject`, derived classes can of course implement those operators! The problem is that the *particular class*, `Button`, doesn't implement `Button& operator=(const Button&)`. One is of course free to implement it and copy all the properties between the buttons. It's not the sanest thing to do, of course.

Comment: That is indeed a lot easier than what I had in mind. Thank you very much!